# pandas multiindex columns from an other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

The first one is like that:

|  | F2 | F1 | F3 | F4 | F5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 8 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 2020 | 9 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 1 |
| 2021 | 10 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 1 |

The second one like that

|  | ID | ASSET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | F1 | carac3 |
| 1 | F2 | carac1 |
| 2 | F3 | carac1 |
| 3 | F4 | carac2 |
| 4 | F5 | carac2 |

I would like to get a multiliindex columns dataframe with :

|  | F2 | F1 | F3 | F4 | F5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | carac1 | carac3 | carac1 | carac2 | carac2 |
| 2019 | 8 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 2020 | 9 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 1 |
| 2021 | 10 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 1 |

Thx

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` the `df1.columns` with `ASSET` then construct Multiindex from them

```py
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(df1.columns, df1.columns.map(df2.set_index('ID')['ASSET'])))
```

```
print(df1)

         F2     F1     F3     F4     F5
     carac1 carac3 carac1 carac2 carac2
2019      8      1      3      4      6
2020      9      1      3      6      1
2021     10      2      4      5      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign back mapped values by another DataFrame by [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
df1.columns = [df1.columns, 
               df1.columns.map(df2.set_index('ID')['ASSET'])]
print (df1)
         F2     F1     F3     F4     F5
     carac1 carac3 carac1 carac2 carac2
2019      8      1      3      4      6
2020      9      1      3      6      1
2021     10      2      4      5      1
```

Or with `rename`:

```
df1.columns = [df1.columns, 
               df1.rename(columns=df2.set_index('ID')['ASSET']).columns]
print (df1)
         F2     F1     F3     F4     F5
     carac1 carac3 carac1 carac2 carac2
2019      8      1      3      4      6
2020      9      1      3      6      1
2021     10      2      4      5      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) constructor and a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2.merge(df1.columns.to_series(name='ID'),
                                   how='right'))
```

*NB. this makes it easy to add any number of levels in case `df2` has more columns.*

Output:

```
ID        F2     F1     F3     F4     F5
ASSET carac1 carac3 carac1 carac2 carac2
2019       8      1      3      4      6
2020       9      1      3      6      1
2021      10      2      4      5      1
```